# Photo ski-passes in Arabba Italy

Tags: tickets, italy, skiing

Are ski-passes in Arabba issued for a particular person (i.e. do they have a photo associated with them)? Does it apply to all durations?

Also are there any free lifts near the town (to teach the small children without having a ski-pass)? This is often the case in French resorts.

Comment: To me this looks like two precise questions: one about ski passes and another one about nursey slopes. Maybe they should be split?

Comment: @MarcelC., I think you are right. I will ask (a bit more general) question about the second part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have just been in the ski pass office.

There is no photo associated with ski-passes up to 7 days. However, there is the ski-passes starting from 2 days have the gender of the holder associated with it. Of course, sharing or swapping a ski-pass is illegal, and may result in confiscation of the ski-pass if found.

To answer the second half of the question, there don't seem to be any free lifts.

UPDATE: I also found out that if your child has at most 3 years, you can buy a special family skipass (20% more expensive than the corresponding normal one), which can be shared between the parents. If you do the math, it becomes cheaper than multiple one day passes starting from 7 days.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this UK forum post](https://www.snowheads.co.uk/ski-forum/viewtopic.php?t=23761) there is no photo on the Arabba ski-passes.

Some quotes from the thread:

> I went to arabba last year and got back from selva on the 27th Jan this year. Got my lift pass through Inghams both times but never needed a photo.

---

> Was in Arabba last week. No photo needed, and no photo taken in lift pass offfice.

Answer (score 3):

Although no picture is taken when printing the pass, some ski lift access control systems are able to detect if a single pass is used by different persons.

This applies to some systems that use barcode or RFID passes and turnstiles. For instance, one of the newest Skidata systems takes a picture of the user at the turnstile at each passage. The guard inside the booth near the turnstiles is able to see on a computer all the different pictures that were taken in association with the pass. Thus, any swapping can be easily busted.

Comment: Wow, they go really long way to detect these things! I don't think they have these systems here in Arabba yet, but I am not sure obviously.